# Cardinal characteristics of the ideal of $\sigma$-continuity of the Pawlikowski function

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-characteristics

A function $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is called *$\sigma$-continuous* if there exists a countable cover $\mathcal C$ of $X$ such that for every $C\in\mathcal C$ the restriction $f{\restriction}C$ is continuous.

A typical example of a function (of the first Baire class) which is not $\sigma$-continuous is the Pawlikowski function $P:(\omega+1)^\omega\to\omega^\omega$ (which is defined as the countable power $P=f^\omega$ of a bijection $f:\omega+1\to\omega$).

Let $\mathcal I_P$ be the $\sigma$-ideal of subsets $X$ of the compact metrizable space $(\omega+1)^\omega$ such that $P{\restriction}X$ is $\sigma$-continuous.

> I am interesting in evaluating the standard cardinal characteristics $\mathrm{add}(\mathcal I_P)$, $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal I_P)$, $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)$, $\mathrm{cof}(\mathcal I_P)$ of the $\sigma$-ideal $\mathcal I_P$.

It seems that among these four cardinal characteristics only the covering number $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal I_P)$ was studied in the literature. In particular,
Cichoń, Morayne, Pawlikowski and Solecki<sup>1</sup> proved that $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal I_P)\ge\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ where $\mathcal M$ is the $\sigma$-ideal of
meager subset in $\mathbb R$. Steprāns<sup>2</sup> gave a combinatorial description of the ideal $\mathcal I_P$ and proved the consistency of the strict inequality $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal I_P)>\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$. Steprans also observed that for every $A\in\mathcal I_P$ the image $P(A)$ is a meager subset of $\omega^\omega$, which implies that  $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal I_P)\ge\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ and $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)\le\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$. On the other hand, [it can be shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.00305) that $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)\ge\mathfrak p$.

It is well-known that the strict inequality $\mathfrak p<\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ is consistent. In particular, according to Table 4 in [the survey paper of Blass](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/hbk.pdf), this strict inequality holds in the random, Hechler, Laver, and Mathias forcing models.

> **Problem 1.** Which of the inequalities $\mathfrak p<\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)$ and $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)<\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ is consistent?
>
> **Problem 2.** What is the value of $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal I_P)$ (and other cardinal characteristics of the ideal $\mathcal I_P)$ in the random, Hechler, Laver, and Mathias forcing models?

<sup>1</sup>
J. Cichoń, M. Morayne, J. Pawlikowski and S. Solecki: [Decomposing Baire Functions](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Cichon+Moraine+Pawlikowski+Solecki+Decomposing+Baire+Functions), The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 56, No. 4 (Dec., 1991), pp. 1273-1283. [DOI: 10.2307/2275474](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275474), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275474)

<sup>2</sup> Juris Steprāns: [A Very Discontinuous Borel Function](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Steprans+A+Very+Discontinuous+Borel+Function), The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 58, No. 4 (Dec., 1993), pp. 1268-1283. [DOI: 10.2307/2275142](https://doi.org/10.2307/2275142), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275142)